# CUDA Tried to allocate 1207.54GiB to a GPU!!! Using langchain's CSVLoader over an custom HuggingFace PEFT model

Tags: pytorch, huggingface, langchain

Full code is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-M7go5i_KdtbyWoQB13adzuGehPaaCil#scrollTo=LVv2z1QvPAS4).

Basically trying to load a model finetuned with LoRa and a csv document to query over. CUDA is requiring an absurd amount of memory for a doc that is just 1.6Mb.

everything loads fine until the last line:

```
a = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)
```

when it yields:

```
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. 
Tried to allocate 1207.54 GiB (GPU 0; 14.62 GiB total capacity; 11.04 GiB already allocated; 2.79 GiB free; 11.32 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  
See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

Is there something wrong? Is there any way I can make this run without having to get all this memory?